# Coordinate/attribute not working to mix textures through factor

Tags: texturing, node-editor

I am still quite new to blender, I am trying to make a small mountain scene with different textures on the higher points of the mountain vs the lower ones.

I am currently using a coordinate node with a colour ramp and mix node to control it. However, when I plug the colour ramp into the factor of the mix shader only one of the textures occupies the entire object. I tried a simpler way by using an attribute node and vertex groups but I had the same issue.

I've searched for an answer online but haven't found anything relating to this issue. I've also looked at several tutorials on this and I believe the node set-up is correct but they still wont play nicely together.

Any info as to what I'm doing wrong would be hugely helpful as this is a relatively small part of a larger scene and I don't want it to cause the whole thing to look janky lol

[give it a look](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Wp0MmGryx2vbdWkZ-51EoS14eMvoz2Jr)

Answer (score 1):

Use the same method however, use vertex paint instead of weight. Use the Attribute Node and the name of the Vertex color layer (default is "Col"). For example, use pure black for rock and pure white vertex color for snow.

[image]
[image]

Also, not sure what kind of displacement you're trying to achieve but you cannot use a Mix RGB node as input to the Displacement output which expects a vector. Use the Displacement node in between.

[image]
[image]